# Calling different functions in Struct (C)

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, parameters

I am struggeling with a problem and I hope someone can help me.

I have a struct like this:

```
struct example {

     char *name;

      int (*func1)(int x, char c, double z);
      int (*func2)(int x, float y, char c);

   }example;
```

So I got 2 function pointers with a parameterlist. In my case, I want to adjust these functions with a different set of parameters, depending on the name of the value of the variable "name".

I need to have these function pointers in my struct and I also cannot just add other functions to it. Has anyone an idea how to implement it?

BR

Comment: Please post the *actual* code.  `*char name;` is obviously a syntax error, so the posted code will not compile.  Did you mean `char *name;`?  What other differences are there?

Comment: Frankly I suspect we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and that the answer to your actual problem might be "Use C++". If not the answer, I am afraid, might be "Impossible with those restrictions you describe." Both means that you should try to take one logical step back and try to describe what you want to achieve by doing what you describe.

Comment: @TomKarzes is basically right. But the best thing to show here is a [mre] which demonstrates what you want to do, what problem you have with it, or preferrably both. (Tom, I assume you know the magic shortcut of typping `[mre]` into appropriate comments like yours.)

Comment: What does *" I want to adjust these functions with a different set of parameters"* mean?  Are you saying that you want to call either `func1` or `func2` depending on the value of `name`?

Comment: I probably misinterpret the question, but it seem like you just want `if(strcmp(example.name, "foo")) {example.func1(x, c, z); } else { example.func2(x, y, c);}`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a union that lets you define the pointers as pointers to functions having different signatures. It's a bit clunky but you get the benefit of the compiler warning you if pass inappropriate function parameters.

```
struct example {
   char *name;
   union {
      struct {
         int (*func1)(int x, char c, double z);
         int (*func2)(int x, float y, char c);
       } type1;
       struct {
         int (*func1)(char *p1);
         int (*func2)(int x, char *p1);
       } type2;
    } u;
} example;
```

Given an instance of `example`:

```
struct example *e = flar(some parameters);
```

You can execute `func1` or `func2` like this:

```
if (!strcmp(e->name, "type1")) {
   int r1 = e->u.type1.func1(1, 'a', 3.5);
   int r2 = e->u.type1.func2(2, 4.2, 'b');
} else if (!strcmp(e->name, "type2")) {
   int r1 = e->u.type2.func1("42");
   int r2 = e->u.type2.func2(42, "6*7");
} else {
   fprintf(stderr, "bad name '%s'\n", e->name);
   exit(1);
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify them as having no parameters but you'll have to make sure, as Raymond mentions, all functions are defined using promoted types where promotion would otherwise happen. Of course, when you do it that way the compiler won't be able to warn you if you make a mistake in the caller.

Comment: "you can specify them as having no parameters" - in this case you can't since some of the parameters are `char` and `float` which are promoted to `int` and `double` (respectively) in the absence of a prototype.